# What is exact raster cell size in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I used worldclim 2.5 arc minutes data set for creation of ASCII file. According to worldclim 2.5 ac minutes represent spatial resolution of 4.5 km, therefore the cell size 4.5 x 4.5 = 20.25km2. but the properties of ASCII file showing cell size of 0.1 (x) and 0.1 (y), therefore the cell size is 0.01 square.

What is the correct one to calculate area of the desired pixel or cell in QGIS?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: My previous claim was false and I apologize for that. I thought I knew of arc-minute and all but I clearly had no idea. Here is the actuality:

2.5 arc minute data set is each pixel being worth 2.5/60 of one degree (since 1 degree is made of 60 minutes, and each of these is 60 seconds)

You can view the resolution in raster properties under Metadata and Properties. In this you will find your raster's dimensions as well as pixel size, however be careful. Pixel size will depend on the coordinate system you are using. In your case, I am thinking pixel size being 0.1 is due to it's value in regarding it's unit of measurement.
[image]

Comment: 2.5 arc minute is the spatial resolution of the raster meaning it's the pixel size. A pixel is 2.5 x 2.5 arc minutes.

Comment: Thank you for commenting this, you are indeed right and I have modified my answer to sum up what an arc minute is. I apologize for being misleading.

Comment: In my case the "Dimensions" part shows many many pairs of values